# Express.js get http method in controller

Tags: http, node.js, express

I am building a registration form (passport-local as authentication, forms as form helper).

Because the registration only knows GET and POST I would like to do the whole handling in one function.

With other words I am searching after something like:

```
exports.register = function(req, res){
    if (req.isPost) {
       // do form handling
    }
    res.render('user/registration.html.swig', { form: form.toHTML() });
};
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The answer was quite easy

```
exports.register = function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
       // do form handling
    }
    res.render('user/registration.html.swig', { form: form.toHTML() });
};
```

But I searched a long time for this approach in the express guide.

Finally the node documentation has such detailed information:
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Right. It is pity that the express.js document has missed these things here http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params and it doesn't refer the documentation of the NodeJS built-in library, which is really necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting this solution.  For me though, to make the logic work as you have listed there, I had to make my IF statement this way : `if (req.method != 'GET')`

Comment: It would be better if you use triple equal character instead of double equal when you compare strings

Answer (score -5):

Now you can use a package in npm => "method-override", which provides a middle-ware layer that overrides the "req.method" property.

Basically your client can send a POST request with a modified "req.method", something like `/registration/passportID?_method=PUT`.

The

> ?_method=XXXXX

portion is for the middle-ware to identify that this is an undercover PUT request.

The flow is that the client sends a POST req with data to your server side, and the middle-ware translates the req and run the corresponding "app.put..." route.

I think this is a way of compromise. For more info: [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override)