# re.params, get(name or value) from external function in Node js?

Tags: node.js, routes

How to get the `req.params` values or names to access it?

I need something like `req.params = {track:'somevalue'}` or `{id: 123}` ....

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.method == 'GET'){
    var data = req.params; //params is undefined    
  }
})

app.get('/info/:track', (req, res) => {})
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {})
app.get('/courses/:session', (req, res) => {})
app.get('/somethingelse/:last', (req, res) => {})
```

Comment: Can you `console.log` anything inside your if clause in the middleware?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js get http method in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168115/express-js-get-http-method-in-controller)